# Creating a data store from a GetCapabilities WFS URL

Tags: java, geoserver-rest-api

I'm coding a geoserver manager with geoserver rest api (version 1.7) and I'm looking for a function that can create a data store from a GetCapabilities WFS URL.

Inside Geoserver, I go to "Store - Add new store - Web Feature Server", but I'm not sure if I can do that programmatically.

I don't want the code done, of course, but only the class I can use to get there.

I've looked for a function inside every data store related class here http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/gsman/apidocs/index.html?it/geosolutions/geoserver/rest/GeoServerRESTPublisher.html but I wasn't succeeded.

Is it possible to code?

Comment: it's possible that you need to contribute this code, cascaded WFS are not used very often

Comment: I want to contribute. How can I do that?

Comment: see https://github.com/geosolutions-it/geoserver-manager